# SearchString search operation with forename and surname

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql

Hi I have one search box that takes searchstring and search it in the database. The input are like "utsav pal", "utsav p", "pal" for the account Name Utsav Pal. But I want to use only the initials like "uts pa". Can any one suggest me what can I do ?

Here is the logic I have used

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.SearchString)){
 accounts = accounts.where( a => 
       ((a.Forname != null) && (a.Forename +"  "+ a.Surname).IndexOf(vm.SearchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 ) ||
      ((a.AccountCode != null) && a.AccountCode.IndexOf(vm.SearchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 )
```

Comment: *"But I want to use only the initials"* What do you mean my this? The initials for someone called "utsav pal" would be "u" and "p", not "uts pa"·

Comment: You can test first if `Forename + "  " + Surname` contains input. If return is null, split input before and after space. After splitting test both separated inputs with Forename and after that with Surname.

Comment: Hi, Marko Ivkovic can you please explain me with example ?

Comment: Steps of my logic is: 
1. `(a.Forename +" "+ a.Surname).IndexOf(vm.SearchString)`   
2. `strings = vm.SearchString.Split(" ")
foreach (string singleString in strings)
a.Forename.IndexOf(singleString)`     
3. `strings = vm.SearchString.Split(" ")
foreach (string singleString in strings)
a.Surname.IndexOf(singleString)`   
Next step will execute only if previous return null. 
Note: i don't know C#, so syntax maybe not 100% correct

Comment: Hi Marko I have tried your logic but it didn't work !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the logic below. I have created a Person model class and a repository class for the data based on the Person model.
The first code snippet is The Person Model and Repository Classes.

```
public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string ForeName { get; set; }
            public string SurName { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }

        public static class Repository
        {
            public static List<Person> p { get; set; }
            static Repository()
            {
                p = new List<Person>();
                p.Add(new Person
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    ForeName = "Nafi",
                    SurName = "Ahmadi",
                    Email = "Nafi@example.com"
                });
                p.Add(new Person
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    ForeName = "Shafiq",
                    SurName = "Rahman",
                    Email = "Shafiq@example.com"
                });
                p.Add(new Person
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    ForeName = "Wali",
                    SurName = "Mohammad",
                    Email = "Wali@example.com"
                });
            }
        }
```

Here is the logic that uses initial letters to search in repository data.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Data set
            List<Person> a = Repository.p;

            // Search string
            string SearchStringInput = "N A";

            // Split search string
            string[] SearchString = SearchStringInput.Split(" "); 
            
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchStringInput))
            {
                var p = a.Where(x =>
                ((x.ForeName != null)) && ((x.ForeName.ElementAt(0).ToString() == SearchString[0].ToString()) || x.ForeName.ToString() == SearchString[0].ToString()) && (x.SurName.ElementAt(0).ToString() == (SearchString[1].ToString())) || (x.SurName.ToString() == (SearchString[1].ToString())));

                foreach (var item in p)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Email);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Naveed Thanks for you answer now I am able to search account using the initial letters but still not possible if I search like this "U Pal" for Utsav Pal

Comment: @UtsavPal I have updated my answer. Now it works both for initials and full word search.

Comment: @UtsavPal If this helps you, accept it as the answered question. and upvote it.

Comment: Your code work perfectly for my but now it also displays the code with blank records, like in my database there is some record which doesn't have forename and surname. So when I search other names like "SUS" for SUSAN BAILEY. It shows two records 1. SUSAN BAILEY & 2.                 (Blank)